# Zustand: useStore.setState({ id: 22 }) vs setId(22) (Defining an action function in the store that sets ID)

Tags: reactjs, state, state-management, zustand

Suppose I have a store that looks something like this:

```
const useStore = create((set) => ({
  id: 0,
  name: "",
}));
```

Is it okay if I don't define actions in the store if I don't need to run any extra logic and use the `setState` function  to set `id` and `name` directly in the component?

```
const SomeComp = () => {
  const { setState } = useStore;

  setState({ id: 22 });
  setState({ name: "John" });
  
  return (...);
}
```

Or it'd be better to define actions in the store and use them in your component?

```
const useStore = create((set) => ({
  id: 0,
  name: "",
  setId: (id) => set({ id }),
  setName: (name) => set({ name }),
}));
```

One benefit of using action functions that I see in this case is that you can implement the bailout behavior. (setName or setId would set the passed value only if it's not the same value as the current state value):

```
setName: (name) => {
  if (name === get().name) return;
  return set({ name });
},
```

Is is okay to do this type of check inside of the action function? Or would it be more appropriate to check if values are equal manually before calling setName or using useStore.setState({ name })?

Thanks!